# WP Plugin: Updraft Plus Restore function not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins, google-drive-api, restore

Im testing out the Updraft Plus plugin to make sure it will work with my site, so I created a wordpress site with a simple theme and a backed it up to my Google Drive folder. Everything went fine. Updraft Plus uploaded all the backup files and I deleted my site.

I reinstalled wordpress and installed updraft again to see if it will restore my site. The issue that I'm having is that updraft does not sync with the Google Drive backup folder and it does not see the back up files it created.

I followed all the step and made sure that all the settings where setup right, and I authenticated with Google. But when I click "restore" and "rescan folder for new backup sets" Updraft Plus still says "No backup has been completed".

How do I get Updraft Plus to see the backups in my Google Drive folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UpdraftPlus doesn't (yet) re-scan remote storage if you're trying to connect from a second site. Instead, download the files manually and drag-and-drop them into the relevant part in the "Restore" section.

David

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, that UpdraftPlus does now have this feature, and can re-scan remote storage - since something like two or three months ago.